# Passing an object that implements map to a binary search function?

Tags: sql, algorithm, object, plsql

I've got some sql objects stored in a table that implement the map function to allow them to be compared. I'm wondering if I can pass a sorted list of them to a binary search function that will work on anything which implements the map() function?

Something like

```
function binarySearch(mappables typ_mappables_t) return integer is
begin
    --binary search using map() for comparison
    return found_index;
end;
```